# Solidity compilation issue on Linux Mint

Tags: solidity, solc, linux

I have a smart contract which I am invoking through webjs. Everything works well untill I am on Windows.
Recently i had to move to Linux Mint. Now when i compile the contract. I get stdin in the compiled code.
Becuase of this, I am not able to access the value of code.
I verified the issue by running a simple smart contract on the command line, as follows-

```
>eth.getCompilers()
["Solidity"]
> var testSource='contract Test {  function double(int a) constant returns(int) { return 2*a; } }';
undefined
> var testCompiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(testSource);
undefined
> testCompiled
{
  <stdin>:Test: {
    code: "0x60606040523415600b57fe5b5b60788061001a6000396000f300606060405263ffffffff60e060020a6000350416636ffa1caa81146020575bfe5b3415602757fe5b60306004356042565b60408051918252519081900360200190f35b600281025b9190505600a165627a7a72305820bf2f987fd5895006a3af08154264d6de5a6d35b25eb3f85572f8264ab26db1b70029",
    info: {
      abiDefinition: [{...}],
      compilerOptions: "--combined-json bin,abi,userdoc,devdoc --add-std --optimize",
      compilerVersion: "0.4.9",
      developerDoc: {
        methods: {}
      },
      language: "Solidity",
      languageVersion: "0.4.9",
      source: "contract Test {  function double(int a) constant returns(int) { return 2*a; } }",
      userDoc: {
        methods: {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note I have tried compiling this with both with stable solc version for Linux and latest dev version of Solc with same results.